# How to add my own html template in django

Tags: python, django

I am new in django, my problem is how to give a link to css and js

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Welcome</title>   
     <link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/templatemo_style.css" %}" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

css and js not load from actual path, dont know how to use actual path of static folder in html
i am trying to use

```
import os
#DIRNAME = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

But it give me the wrong path

i am providing a brief description:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static/'),
}
```

my url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/home/
```

error showing

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
    D:\Eclipse_JEE_new_workspace\testing\testing\static\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
```

It showing:

```
D:\Eclipse_JEE_new_workspace\testing\testing\static\index.html
```

but actual

If i moved static folder in testing folder, its me an html page without css and js link

```
D:\Eclipse_JEE_new_workspace\testing\static\index.html
```

---

Sorry for more description before now situation is:

when page load css link give me an error 404 but same position index.html page load
how to include css/js?
In current situation, i am using 
{% include 'header.html' %}
to include in index.html

Comment: Did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/? Static files are *not* templates.

Comment: yes i did @MartijnPieters

Comment: it give me an error in "static" keyword

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to ask about that then? You can [edit] your question to at least add that you tried that too and what errors you got.

Comment: Error: 'static' takes at least one argument (path to file)

Comment: Without seeing your template that is hard to diagnose. Please update your question and add that detail.

Comment: it's update ... showing 404 error on css link

Comment: The static file path is missing

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'd:/Eclipse_JEE_new_workspace/blog/static/',
    }
    
<br>
thank you to martijn-pieters and dan-klasson for help me!

Answer (score 1):

Template files should go in the `templates` folder. And `DIRNAME` has the path to the `settings.py`.

Should probably be something like:

```
DIRNAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'templates/'),
}
```

And make sure your `index.html` is in the `templates` folder.

Comment: This is not about templates but about static files; I fear the OP has got the two muddled because a first attempt at including static files didn't work.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css

'css\style.css' could not be found

Comment: The static file path is missing

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'd:/Eclipse_JEE_new_workspace/blog/static/',
    }
    
<br>
thank you to martijn-pieters and dan-klasson for help me!